# jQuery add a class after fadeOut completly done

Tags: jquery

Here is the code:

```
<style>
#box1, #box2, .container { position: absolute; top: 0px;z-index:10; height: 50px; }
#box1 { background-color: #ff0000; width: 100px; left: 200px; }
.container { width: 640px; overflow: hidden; height: 50px; background-color:#000; color:#FFF; }
</style>


<div class="container">
<div id="box1"></div>
</div>

<script>
var animateMe = function(targetElement, speed){
    var position = $(targetElement).position();
    var positionA = $(targetElement).position();
    if(positionA.left = '400px'){
        $(targetElement).fadeIn(1000).css({left:'200px'});
    };
    //animate
    $(targetElement).animate(
        {
        'left': '400px'
        },
        {
        duration: speed,
        complete: function(){
            animateMe(this, speed);
            }
        }
    ).fadeOut(1000);
};

$('.container').hover(function(){
    animateMe($('#box1'), 2000);
},
function(){
    $('#box1').stop();
});
</script>
```

What I want is when hover:

1. fadesIn
2. animates to right
3. FadesOut (when fadeOut done resets left position)
4. then again repeats to number 1.

But my code is it resets postition then fadesOut, fadesIn ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/SdS68/

```
var animateMe = function(targetElement, speed){
    $(targetElement).css({ left: '200px' }).fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(targetElement).animate({
            'left': '400px'
        }, {
            duration: speed,
            complete: function() {
                $(this).fadeOut(1000, function() {
                    animateMe(this, speed);
                })
            }
        }).fadeOut(1000);
    });
};
```

Comment: thx works perfectly fine. Both answer works but Jasper's code when mouseout box still visible not disappearing so yours good.

Answer (score 0):

You can use callback functions to delay the execution of some code until other code finishes running:

```
$(targetElement).animate({ 'left' : '400px' }, {
    duration : speed,
    complete : function () {
        var that = this;
        $(that).fadeOut(1000, function () {
            animateMe(that, speed);
        });
    }
});
```

Also `if (positionA.left = '400px)` will always return true since you are not using the conditional operator, the code should be: `if (positionA.left == '400px)` (or you could use `===` to match type and value).